# Prove that $\operatorname{Fr}(A)=\overline A \smallsetminus A^\circ$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $ A\subseteq \langle X,d\rangle$
>
> Prove that $\operatorname{Fr}(A)=\overline A \smallsetminus A^\circ$

We know by definition, $\operatorname{Fr}(A)= \overline A \cap \overline{A^\complement} $

We also know from a lemma we deduced that
$\overline{A^\complement}=(A^\circ)^\complement $

$\therefore \overline A \cap \overline{A^\complement}=\overline A \cap (A^\circ)^\complement $

Since $A^\circ\subseteq A \therefore A^\circ\subseteq \overline A \tag{$*$}$

Thus $\overline A \cap (A^\circ)^\complement = \overline A \smallsetminus A^\circ \tag{$**$}$

Now how can we conclude the step $(**)$ from the step $(*) $

Comment: Just use the fact that $A \cap B^c = A \setminus B$ for any two sets $A,B$.

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle X,d\rangle,$ not $<X,d>. \qquad$

Comment: Where you had $A /\ B,$ I presumed that you meant why I might call $A\smallsetminus B$ and I edited accordingly. But now I wonder if you meant something else, since it's trivial that $A\cap B^\complement$ is the same thing as $A\smallsetminus B. \qquad$

Comment: It was a typo, the correct one is yours. So as you say it is trivial :)